# How to build-in a static Qt plugin into an application with CMake?

Tags: qt, plugins, cmake

I'd like to embed a custom virtual audio device plugin into an application. The `QAudioSystemPlugin` looks suitable for this task.

But it doesn't load.

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(myproject)

find_package(Qt5 5.5.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    Core
    Multimedia
)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
add_definitions("-DQT_STATICPLUGIN")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
    VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Multimedia
)

set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QAudioDeviceInfo>
#include <QtPlugin>

Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    for (const auto& dev : QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioInput))
        std::cerr << dev.deviceName().toStdString() << "\n";

    return app.exec();
}
```

**VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin.hpp**:

```
#pragma once

#include <QtMultimedia/QAudioSystemPlugin>

class VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin: public QAudioSystemPlugin
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.qt-project.qt.audiosystemfactory/5.0" FILE "virtual.json")

public:
    VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin() {}

    virtual QList<QByteArray> availableDevices(QAudio::Mode mode) const override;
    virtual QAbstractAudioInput* createInput(const QByteArray& device) override;
    virtual QAbstractAudioOutput* createOutput(const QByteArray& device) override;
    virtual QAbstractAudioDeviceInfo* createDeviceInfo(const QByteArray& device, QAudio::Mode mode) override;
};
```

**VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin.cpp**:

```
#include "VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin.hpp"

#include <iostream>

VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin::VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin(QObject *parent) :
        QAudioSystemPlugin(parent)
{
    std::cerr << "VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin\n";
}

QList<QByteArray> VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin::availableDevices(QAudio::Mode mode) const
{
    std::cerr << "VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin\n";
}

QAbstractAudioInput* VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin::createInput(const QByteArray &device)
{
    std::cerr << "VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin\n";
}

QAbstractAudioOutput* VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin::createOutput(const QByteArray &device)
{
    std::cerr << "VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin\n";
}

QAbstractAudioDeviceInfo* VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin::createDeviceInfo(const QByteArray &device, QAudio::Mode mode)
{
    std::cerr << "VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin\n";
}
```

**virtual.json**:

```
{
    "Keys": ["default"]
}
```

Build and launch: the constructor of the `VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin` is not executed.

How to make it load?

update: I've tried to make it a dynamic plugin too, it shows fine with `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1`, but doesn't get created or called.

**update**: `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` shows nothing related to the plugin when the plugin is built in statically.

This is when the pluging is a separate library (shows, but still doesn't work):

(note that I've also replaced 'default' in `virtual.json` with 'virtual')

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/audio" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/audio/libqtaudio_alsa.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/audio/libqtaudio_alsa.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.audiosystemfactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "alsa"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QAlsaPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 328961
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("alsa")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/audio/libqtmedia_pulse.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/audio/libqtmedia_pulse.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.audiosystemfactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "default"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QPulseAudioPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 328961
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("default")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/data/hd2/tmp/plugins/build/audio" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/data/hd2/tmp/plugins/build/audio/libmyproject.so"
Found metadata in lib /data/hd2/tmp/plugins/build/audio/libmyproject.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.audiosystemfactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "virtual"
        ]
    },
    "className": "VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin",
    "debug": true,
    "version": 328961
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("virtual")
loaded library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/audio/libqtaudio_alsa.so"
loaded library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/audio/libqtmedia_pulse.so"
loaded library "/data/hd2/tmp/plugins/build/audio/libmyproject.so"
```

Comment: "static plugin" is a contradictory statement.You can _either_ link something, _or_ plug it in at runtime.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus, there is the same issue with the dynamic plugin, so I don't think that the cause is in static vs dynamic. "Static plugin" is part of Qt terminology: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#static-plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of the 'default' in **virtual.json**: it was overridden by other plugins. If there are no other plugins, the object is instantiated.

Had to change to something different like 'virtual'.

```
{
    "Keys": ["virtual"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it should rather be something like:

```
class VirtualQAudioSystemPlugin : public QAudioSystemPlugin, public QAudioSystemPluginExtension
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.qt-project.qt.audiosystemfactory/5.0" FILE "virtual.json")
    Q_INTERFACES(QAudioSystemPluginExtension)
etc.
```

You can also set the QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS environment variable to 1 to get more information about what is happening.

Comment: Why there is a need for the `QAudioSystemPluginExtension`?

Comment: Because the factory that will look for audio system plugins will search for plugins implementing that interface.

Comment: SGaist, why it's in private headers and why it doesn't exist in 5.7 then?

Comment: Because it's a plugin implementation detail. And that kind of stuff can change between Qt version. From a quick look at the code, the default device handling has been modified and improved in Qt 5.8.

Comment: So it can't be used and doesn't help (from what it looks like)?

Comment: You should take a look at the QtMultimedia module sources from your installed 5.7 and check the various platforms QAudioSystemPlugin. That should give you the hints you need to implement your custom plugin.

Comment: That's how I did it. I looked at alsa and pulse plugins and made the same code. But it didn't work (and they don't use CMake).

Comment: Did you set `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS` to 1 ? If so, what does it print about your plugin ?

Comment: I can compile a dynamic plugin that works as expected with qmake. How to do that with CMake? Also, added output of QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS. You mean that on your machine it works correctly?